# preventDefault action of many forms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've many forms named `editForm` and called `preventDefault` on them but, not working. My JS is like this:

```js
var editFormData = $('form[name="editForm"]')

// Want to prevent action of each form and set action, but not working
editFormData.submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('submission cancelled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="editForm">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<form name="editForm">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<form name="editForm">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<form name="editForm">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The code in your question works fine, as you can see in the snippet I edited in to it. If it's not working for you then there is an underlying problem in your code. Check the console for errors.

Comment: Could your form(s) be generated after your code runs?  Add your code in doc.ready for a start, then consider event delegation `$(document).on("submit", "form[name='editForm']", function...`  (there's an edge case where event delegation doesn't work, not sure if it's form submit)

Comment: Simple test is to add `console.log(editFormData.length)` just before your `.submt(...` line - if it's zero, there's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A javascript native way to prevent all forms from default behaivor:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('form[name="editForm"]').forEach(node => {
    node.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
    })
})
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but you might like to review what [.submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) does in jquery - and `form`'s don't generally get `click` events when being submitted...

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Indeed I didn't know the jQuery function. However the code is doing what he want :D

Comment: 1) multiple elements with the same `name` is fine, and will not cause the only the first element to be found. You seem to be confusing `name` and `id` here. 2) Attaching the `click` event to the entire `form` element will have other consequences and is counter-productive, in a negative way. 3) The OPs code is valid and does not show the problem described, so it's safe to say that this is an X/Y question and the issue is likely to do with configuration (ie. jQuery.js reference missing, or no document.ready handler, dynamic content etc)

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the advice. Didn't know the submit function from jQuery (just thought he is using it to select elements). I updated my post. :)

Comment: I don't see how this can be an accepted answer when the code in the question already works.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'n confused as well.... However probably he copied my script into his project and it work. Idk :D